# How do I fix Android Studio 2.2 failing to recognise jar?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I've recently upgraded from Studio 2.1 to 2.2, and in a project I have some library dependencies, brought in with good old:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

In Studio 2.1, all of the jars work perfectly. But for some reason, in 2.2, one of the jars doesn't seem to be recognised by the IDE - it doesn't have the expanding triangle next to it, and the classes in it aren't accessible. Building the project works just fine, so the gradle files are clearly correct. But Studio 2.2 just doesn't recognise it.

There are no obvious errors. I've tried repeatedly resyncing the config with gradle, clean builds etc. but nothing seems to work. Only thing I can think of that might be causing it is that the JAR is pretty large (2.6MB), but boosting memory size doesn't seem to help.

Has anyone encountered this, or have any suggestions for fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

Have exactly the same issue - I think that making the jars "provided" dependencies does work around the issue, but obviously is not a via solution.

Comment: I found building a new (slightly different) version of the jar made things work perfectly again. So problem solved for now, but there must have been something about the previous jar (not the size, it would appear) that was causing this behaviour.